# How to match one keyword from phrase in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns. When user input two words for search, it should return partial matched row. Example: user search input= `"a bb"`

sample database table contact :

```
firstname,lastname
========   ==========
a         , bb ccc
d         , ee fff
g         , hh iii
```

**Sample SQL Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM contact 
where firstname like %a bb%
   or lastname  like %a bb%
```

Comment: `firstname like 'a%' or lastname like '%bb%'`

Comment: replace space by `%` and `concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE ...`, or something like that

Comment: @RiggsFolly , Thanks . I will follow the rules and checklist when asking question.

Comment: @Cid , after concate , result would be 'a bb ccc' and if my string is 'a ccc' , how can i make sure it returns first row ?

Comment: @ZahidRouf you've missed the first part. *"replace space by `%`"*. So, you'll compare `'a bb ccc' LIKE '%a%ccc%'`

Comment: "Sample SQL Query" - OK, so what happens when you try to run that? Why is that bad? Was it just because you missed the quotes in the `like` operands?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . how about concatenating the columns and changing the pattern:

```
concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) like replace('%a bb%', ' ', '%')
```

This uses `concat_ws()` to allow either of the columns to be `NULL`.